# Invalid identifier coming in dblink procedure and it becomes invalid when i add column to table

Tags: sql, plsql, dblink

I have 2 databases connected using a database link.

As soon as I add a column in my test table in both the databases 
the procedures accessed via the database link become invalid.

A normal insert via a database link works, but as soon as I put it in a procedure it gives compilation errors.

[image]

Comment: Please post the error you received?

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are saying. So, either I'm doing it correctly (and you are not), or ... it is something else. Could you, please, post SQL*Plus session which describes what you wrote?

Comment: That error message merely points you to where the error is. You need to check the compilation errors on the package (TRANSFER_GLF, presumably) to see what the problem is. You can see errors by using `show err` or by querying `user_errors`.

Comment: Post your code as well or a synopsis of what you are doing.